# How to make FloatingActionButton animated?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my `FloatingActionButtons` color to change non-stop or may be to my `FloatingActionButton` to become bigger and than shrink so that it looks like an animation and can get the attention of user.

How can I achieve this? any solution without using `setState();` is appreciated if there are any.

Comment: Can you add what do you mean by not calling setState becuase if you want to change anything then you need setstate.

Comment: Obviously. Any answer would be helpful. If you can help me with `setState` then I can refactor it using state management. The reason I don't like `setState` is my app is very complicated, so, rebuilding entire widget tree, may be for every 100 milliseconds will devestate my app's performance, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using AnimationController.

```
class Delet2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Delet2State createState() => _Delet2State();
}

class _Delet2State extends State<Delet2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.amber)
        .animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.repeat();
    _animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: animation.value,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```